Is SecTaskRef removed from iPhoneOS 18.0 SDK?
After update to  MacOS Sequoia 15.0, I got this error when compiling Cronet in Chromium,
In file included from ../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator.cc:25:
../../base/allocator/partition_allocator/page_allocator_internals_posix.h:49:35: error: unknown type name 'SecTaskRef'; did you mean 'SecTrustRef'?
uint32_t SecTaskGetCodeSignStatus(SecTaskRef task) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.12)); 

look up header files in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS18.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers, no SecTask.h

macOS Sequoia 15.0 and SDKs/iPhoneOS18.0.sdk?

yes, use xCode 16 to compile base subdirectory in Chromium,  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS18.0.sdk

when using xCode 15.2, I could find '#include <Security/SecTask.h>' in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h

Is the question about macOS or the iPhone SDK?

It's about iPhoneOS 18.0 SDK.  On MacOS 15.0, I change xCode from 16.0 to 15.2, errors disappear.
